# 32 kHz crystal freezing problem

Tags: stm32, rtc

I am using a 32 kHz crystal for RTC in STM32F030R8 for time and date. It is freezing all time and when I touch it with my finger, it starts working. What is the problem?
Unfortunately I do not have datasheet for crystal and there is no model or part number on it
[image]

Comment: Bad grounding or bad soldering?

Comment: I checked all of them

Comment: Show your circuit.

Comment: Maybe the crystal is incompatible with the MCU? You did not reveal which exact 32768 Hz crystal you bought, but it is highly important to get one that has suitable specs. Please edit in make/model/datasheet of the crystal into the question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the loading capacitors aren’t right for the crystal.  A typical value for a 32k crystal might be 6pF, but that includes the load contributed by the RTC itself, which may be 1pF or so.

Comment: I tested different capacitors but it does not work

Comment: Would you care to post the datasheet for the crystal and an image of the board layout?

Answer (score 1):

As per your schematic, 22pF capacitors are way off the scale to be suitable for RTC crystals, so you have just wrong capacitors.

Comment: So what should they be?

Comment: @HamedP You were asked multiple times to provide information which exact crystal you bought to be able to give you any guess about correct capacitor values, and you did not give this information so we can't answer until you provide information.

Comment: I know , you are right. Because I do not have a datasheet and part number for it, I asked. Thank you